# Computing the DFT of an arbitrary signal

Tags: matlab, fft, dft, frequency-analysis

As part of a course in signal processing at university, we have been asked to write an algorithm in Matlab to calculate the single sided spectrum of our signal using DFT, without using the `fft()` function built in to matlab. this isn't an assessed part of the course, I'm just interested in getting this "right" for myself. I am currently using the 2018b version of Matlab, should anyone find this useful.

I have built a signal of a 1 KHz and 2KHz sinusoid, phase shifted by 135 degrees (2*pi/3 rad).

then using the equations in 9.1 of *Discrete time signal processing (Allan V. Oppenheim)*  and Euler's formula to simplify the exponent, I produce this code:

```
%%DFT(currently buggy)
n=0;m=0;
for m=1:DFT_N-1 %DFT_Fmin;DFT_Fmax; %scrolls through DFT m values (K in text.)
    for n=1:DFT_N-1;%;(DFT_N-1);%<<redundant code? from Oppenheim eqn. 9.1 % eulers identity, K=m and n=n
        X(m)=x(n)*(cos((2*pi*n*m)/DFT_N)-j*sin((2*pi*n*m)/DFT_N));
        n=n+1;
    end
    %m=m+1; %redundant code?
end
```

This takes x as the input, in this case the signal mentioned earlier, as well as the resolution of the transform, as represented by the DFT_N, which has been initialized to 100. The output of this function, X, should be something in the frequency domain, but plotting X yields a circular plot slightly larger than the unit circle, and with a gap on the left hand edge.

I am struggling to see how I am supposed to convert this to the `stem()` plots as given by the in-built DFT algorithm.

Many thanks, J.

Comment: `X` will in general be complex, hence the circular plot.  If you're interested in the frequency (amplitude) response, typically you'd want to plot the absolute value.

Comment: so as I understand it, a stem plot of the absolute value of x will give the double-sided DFT, and then adding plotting constraints to get single-sided? EDIT

Comment: Note that (a) Matlab already knows how to calculate complex exponentials, you don't have to complicate your code by expanding Euler's identity. and (b) Matlab functions operate just fine on vectors, so you don't need a nested loop.

Comment: (wouldn't let me edit) this produces a plot with X=1.107 globally in the y-axis for all n in the x-axis, in essence a flatline. This makes me think something else is wrong with my plotting technique

Comment: Thanks Ben, normally I use C, so for me nested loops are more intuitive, although I understand they aren't pre-compiled in matlab and are therefore slower. we never had a course in matlab itself, so never go to properly understand the syntax, so as things are I'm just taking it bit by bit... as for the Euler's expansion, I thought about using the real and imaginary parts later for some other things, but again I see its redundant as matlab already has a system in place for separating out the real and imaginary components.

Comment: Note also that `n=n+1` is useless. Matlab overwrites the loop variable `n` when a new iteration begins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the single-sided spectrum only, than you can just calculate X(m) `for m=1:DFT_N/2` since X it is conjugate symmetric around m=DFT_N/2, i.e., `X(DFT_N/2+m) = X(DFT_N/2-m)'`, due to `exp(-j*(pi*n+2*pi/DFT_N*m)) = exp(-j*(pi*n-2*pi/DFT_N*m))'`.

As a side note, for a given m this program calculates an inner product between the array x and another array of complex exponentials, i.e., `exp(-j*2*pi/DFT_N*m*n)`, for n = 0,1,...,N-1. MATLAB syntax is very convenient for such calculations, and you can avoid this inner loop by the following command

```
exp(-j*2*pi/DFT_N*m*(0:DFT_N-1)) * x
```

where x is a column vector. Similarly, you can avoid the first loop  too by expanding your complex exponential vector row-wise for every m, i.e., build the matrix `exp(-j*2*pi/DFT_N*(0:DFT_N-1)'*(0:DFT_N-1))`. Then your DFT is simply

```
X = exp(-j*2*pi/DFT_N*(0:DFT_N-1)'*(0:DFT_N-1)) * x
```

For single-sided spectrum, instead use

```
X = exp(-j*2*pi/DFT_N*(0:floor((DFT_N-1)/2))'*(0:DFT_N-1)) * x
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your bug:

replace  `X(m)=x(n)*(cos..` with  `X(m)=X(m)+x(n)*(cos..`

For a given m, it does not integrate over the variable n, but overwrites X(m) only the last calculation for n = DFT_N-1.

Notice that integrating over `n=1:DFT_N-1` omits one harmonic, i.e., the first one, exp(-j*2*pi). Replace 
`n=1:DFT_N-1` with `n=1:DFT_N` to include that. I would also replace `m=1:DFT_N-1` with `m=1:DFT_N` for plotting concerns.

Also replace any `2*pi*n*m` with `2*pi*(n-1)*(m-1)` to get the phase right, since the first entry of X should correspond to zero-frequency, yielding sum_n x(n) * (cos(0) + j sin(0)) = sum_n x(n). If your signal x is real-valued then the zero-frequency component X(1) should be real-valued, angle(X(1))=0.

Last remark, don't forget to shift zero-frequency component to the center of the spectrum for better visibility, `X = circshift(X,floor(size(X)/2));`